# Putting a scrollable div into table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have the following script:

```
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 300px;background-color: red">
        </td>
        <td style="background-color: lime">
            <div style="width: 50%;overflow: auto;">
                <img src="very_big_image.jpg" />
            </div>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 400px;background-color: orange">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

It sets the width of second `td` equal to the `width` of my `img`,(but logically the second `td` must have the width = `'100% - 300px - 400px'`) so I have the scroll in my whole window.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Doesn't using overflow:scroll; work in this case?

Comment: it doesn't work even with `overflow:hidden` :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the overflow to scroll should acheive what you're looking for:

```
overflow:scroll;
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/WbAEq/

Setting the overflow to auto as you have will only show scroll bars when you're using clipping.

**UPDATE:**

In order to get the table to work with overflow content you need to set the `table-layout` property of the `<table>` to `fixed`

```
table{
table-layout:fixed;
}
```

You can see an example of this here: http://jsfiddle.net/WbAEq/2/

Comment: doesn't work with `overflow:scroll` too, i've tested. In your example you have the scroll in whole window (just like with `overflow:auto`)

Comment: Ah yes. This only seems to occur when the DIV inside the TD has a % based width. If you set the width to px then it works fine.